# Connect to Elasticache from outside with NAT instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, nat, amazon-elasticache, vpc

I'm trying to configure AWS Elasticache access from the outside a VPC via a NAT Instance. The process is quite well documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/accessing-elasticache.html) however every docs point to setup a rule in the `iptables` to forward the traffic to the IP address of Elasticache. The problem raises here because I don't have any IP address but just a DNS name. Am I missing anything?

Comment: after getting private address, through `nslookup/dig` how to add to iptables when i try to add by sshing to machine, it doesn't reflect in `iptables -L -n -v` still showing empty in my NAT instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out the private IP address by pinging the primary endpoint

Comment: Please keep in mind that private IP addresses can change when you restart the ElastiCache instance. That can also happen when Amazon is doing updates during your maintenance window.

Comment: Bummer :-( how then implement forwarding rules in iptables if ip change?

Comment: The question is what are you trying to achieve with it.
Do you have production servers outside AWS which should connect to it, or is it for your local development machine connecting to Elasticache?

Comment: @Pampy production servers outside AWS which should connect to it

Comment: Depending on the infrastructure, I'd rather go with some different approach in that case. You could for example create a VPN connection from your on-premise servers to AWS and have an encrypted connection to your Elasticache instances. AWS supports VPN gateways out of the box, which are also scalable (and not a single point of failure in that case).

Comment: Unfortunately this is not that easy because in that case the outside servers are located in Heroku and Heroku is really expensive for that because you need to set up a private space which come with the Heroku Enterprise plan

Answer (score 0):

Most AWS Managed service endpoints like RDS, ALB, NLB, AD ... will have DNS names for which the IPs can be found by doing nslookup from within the VPC (Internal endpoints).